# HTML Meta and Body parts from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, meta

Is it possible to load html meta attributes from JSON?
for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>{{title}}</title>
<meta charset="{{charset}}">
<meta name="description" content="{{description}}">
<meta name="keywords" content="{{keywords}}">
<script type="text\javascript" src="some_kind_of_script_to_work_with_json_or_so.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{H1}}</h1>
<div>{{some_kind_of_text}}</div>
<div>{{some_kind_of_text2}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can fetch data from a URL using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) and then use standard [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript_technologies_overview#HTML_DOM) methods to change the content of the document.

That said, meta data is generally consumed either as the document loads (so it would be too late to change it for any practical effect by the time JS ran) or is consumed by tools that are likely to not execute JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Quentin said, it is possible but any content you change with JS might not be seen by Google or other search engines.

If your purpose is to load content that needs to be read by a search engine you will want to 'build' the HTML on the server side, using a server side language like PHP for instance.

Comment: i'm wondering about compatibility with google about it.
as i know, google is using javascript to render page, so maybe and seo (meta)  parts will load?

Comment: I work in a SEO company, and Google algorithms are kind of secret so even though we know Google renders js we are not 100% how and which parts of the HTML is rendered this way. Therefore we just stick to the secure way, which is building it on the server side.
If you are not confortable using server side technologies you may want to test it with the JS solution and see how Google renders it.

Comment: as i see, need some test's, everything is about google. the thing is that for the template (php/html) i would use memcached, that's why i want to use json or something similar to make like api service and load dynamic data there